# Android: Repeat a method and delay other method after x seconds using handle

Tags: android

I'm new to android and i have a problem
I used same code to repeat and delay method for two class. One class work fine but other not. I don't know why. This is my code

**SpeedMeterFragment.java**

```
public class SpeedMeterFragment extends Fragment {
    ....
    public void speedMeterBefore() {
        totalRxBytesBefore = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes();
        Log.d("test", "Before: " + String.valueOf(totalRxBytesBefore));
    }

    public void speedMeterAfter() {
        totalRxBytesAfter = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes();
        Log.d("test", "After: " + String.valueOf(totalRxBytesAfter));
    }

    public void speedMeterDifference() {
        totalRxBytesDifference = totalRxBytesAfter - totalRxBytesBefore;
        tvTest.setText(String.valueOf(totalRxBytesDifference/1024) + " kb/s");
        Log.d("test", "Difference: " + String.valueOf(totalRxBytesDifference));
    }

    public void speedMeter() {
        handler = new Handler();
        handler.post(runnable = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                speedMeterBefore();
                final Handler handler1 = new Handler();
                handler1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        speedMeterAfter();
                        speedMeterDifference();
                    }
                }, 1000);
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and **SaveDataUseage.java**

```
public class SaveDataUseage extends BroadcastReceiver {
    ...

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ...
        savePreference();
    }

    public void savePreference() {
        ...
        measureDataMB();        
    }

    public void measureDataMBBefore() {
        dataMBBefore = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes() / 1048576;
    }

    public void measureDataMBAfter() {
        dataMBAfter = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes() / 1048576;
    }

    public void measureDataMBDifference() {
        dataMBDifference = dataMBAfter - dataMBBefore;
    }

    public void measureDataMB() {
        handler = new Handler();
        handler.post(runnable = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                measureDataMBBefore();
                final Handler handler1 = new Handler();
                handler1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        measureDataMBAfter();
                        measureDataMBDifference();
                    }
                }, 1000);
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

SpeedMeterFragment work fine, but not SaveDataUseage
Anybody help me?
Sorry for my bad English :)

Comment: Could you explain the handler inside the handler ?

Comment: Have you tried logging whether the receiver is activated? Does it reach the measureDataMB() function?

Comment: This is what i mean: method1 repeat every 1 second, inside method1 there are method2, and method3 executed after 1 second after method2 called

Answer (score 0):

```
handler = new Handler();

final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

//Your method called here
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};

handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
```

this code will repeat method after every second

Comment: I know but in my method there are other methods to be executed delayed x second after some method called.
That means, method1 repeat every 1 second, inside method1 there are method2, and method3 executed after 1 second after method2 called

Comment: Then You have to write some if else conditions.

Answer (score 0):

```
handler = new Handler();

final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

//Your method called here

MyMethod(isCalledFromHandeler);

        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};

handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
```

use `boolean`  argument `isCalledFromHandeler` to recognition the caller of method.
and then use

```
if(isCalledFromHandeler){
// Do Not call the Child Method

} else{

// Call the Child Method
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although its eight month old question, I also faced the similar problem and in solution I extended [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) class to [AdvanceHandler](https://gist.github.com/murtazakhussain/edb7be99ca74c398c44c) with the postRepeated method.

**Sample Usage**

```
AdvanceHandler handler = new AdvanceHandler();
handler.postRepeated(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Your repeated task
            }
        }, 5000) //After every 5 seconds
```